# Redundant conformance of <view controller> to protocol 'UISearchBarDelegate' - Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, uisearchbardelegate

I have this error

> Redundant conformance of 'TodoListViewController' to protocol 'UISearchBarDelegate'

The error is popping up over "UISearchBarDelegate" on line 1.

```
extension TodoListViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    let request : NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!)

    request.predicate = predicate

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)

    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    do {
        itemArray = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching data from context \(error)")
    }

    tableView.reloadData()

  }
}
```

class declaration for TodoListViewController:

> class TodoListViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

I have researched into this and no other questions are valid to my error.

Comment: Show the declaration for `TodoListViewController`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor check new edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add delegate  at extension  `extension TodoListViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {`

And at Declaration 
`class TodoListViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {`

remove it from declaration

```
class TodoListViewController: UITableViewController {

}
```